# Search for value in array and remove element before and after

Tags: php, arrays, search

I have an array with a lot of content. here and example:

```
Array
    (
    [0] => Value1 
    [1] => Value2
    [2] => Remove
    [3] => Value3
    [4] => Value4
    [5] => Dont remove
    [6] => Value5 
    [7] => Value6
    [8] => Remove
    // etc... 
);
```

I want to search in this array for the element "remove" and remove this element and also remove the two elements before "remove" (value 1, value 2 and value 5 and 6. etc..

How can i manage this in php?

Comment: What do you have so far and what is the problem with it?

Comment: What is the "Dont Remove" for?

Answer (score 2):

A simple `foreach` loop would suffice - unset the elements if a condition is met, in your case its when the value is `Remove`. Use `unset()` on the current element, and the two before that.

This assumes that your array is numerically indexed without gaps (so the keys start at 0 and increments by 1 each iteration). If they have a chance of being something else, you can store the two prior keys in a variable as you iterate over the array and unset through that.

```php
foreach ($array as $k=>$v) {
    if ($v == 'Remove') {
        unset($array[$k]);
        unset($array[$k-1]);
        unset($array[$k-2]);
    }
}
print_r($array);
```

- Live demo at https://3v4l.org/d48NK

Comment: Recommend a check for `$k` smaller then 2... (Don't want to get exception)

Comment: Calling `unset()` on an undefined elements does not raise notices, warnings or exceptions. Nothing happens!

Comment: Didn't know that - weird that it not even raise notice when doing `unset($a[-1])`...

Comment: It's not explicitly documented that it *doesn't* raise any notices or warnings, but its implied - as there is no documentation of it doing so to begin with.